# The method compare(MedicalShifts, MedicalShifts) in the type Comparator<MedicalShifts> is not applicable for the arguments (P, P)

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to use a comparator on a generic array but it gives me the following error

> The method compare(MedicalShifts, MedicalShifts) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (P, P)Java(67108979)

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EmptyQueueException {
        Queue<MedicalShifts> queueHospital = new QueueImplement<>();
        queueHospital.add(new MedicalShifts("harry", 0));
        queueHospital.add(new MedicalShifts("hermione", 3));
        queueHospital.add(new MedicalShifts("ron", 1));
        queueHospital.add(new MedicalShifts("luna", 5));
        queueHospital.add(new MedicalShifts("voldemort", 8));
        System.out.println(queueHospital.peek());
        System.out.println(queueHospital.isEmpty());
        try {
            System.out.println(queueHospital.pop());
        } catch (EmptyQueueException emptyQueue) {
            System.out.println(emptyQueue.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(queueHospital.peek());
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        queueHospital.add(new MedicalShifts("hagrid", 4));
        for (MedicalShifts shifts : queueHospital) {
            System.out.println(shifts);
        }
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        queueHospital.sort();
        for (MedicalShifts shifts : queueHospital) {
            System.out.println(shifts);
        }
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        System.out.println(queueHospital.min(new Comparator<MedicalShifts>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MedicalShifts o1, MedicalShifts o2) {
                return o1.getNombre().compareTo(o2.getNombre());
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

QueueImplement.java

```
public class QueueImplement<P extends Comparable<P>> implements Queue<P> {
  private P[] elements;
  private static int INITIAL_DIM = 10;
  private int cantidad = 0;

  public QueueImplement() {
    P[] elements = (P[]) new Comparable[INITIAL_DIM]; // Creación de un array de elementos genéricos comparables
    this.elements = elements;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(P persona) throws EmptyQueueException {
    if (cantidad == elements.length) {
      throw new EmptyQueueException();
    }
    elements[cantidad++] = persona;
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public P peek() {
    return elements[0];
  }

  @Override
  public P pop() throws EmptyQueueException {
    P first = elements[0];
    this.elements = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, 1, elements.length); // si hay error, es - 1
    cantidad--;
    return first;
  }

  @Override
  public P min(Comparator<MedicalShifts> comp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
             if (comp.compare(elements[j], elements[j+1]) > 0) {
                  P temp = elements[j];
                  elements[j] = elements[j+1];
                  elements[j+1] = temp;
             }
         }
    }
    return elements[0];
  }

  @Override
  public P max() { // devuelve el nombre mas grandajo. Se puede sortear y dsp agarrar el ultimo
    return elements[cantidad - 1];
  }

  @Override
  public void sort() {
    Arrays.sort(elements, 0, cantidad);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<P> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<P>() {
      private int index = 0;

      @Override
      public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < cantidad;
      }

      @Override
      public P next() {
        return elements[index++];
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return cantidad == 0;
  }
}
```

The error happens on the comp.compare in the min function. All the other methods work perfectly with generics, so I don´t know why it is not working with the compare function that the comparator has.

Comment: Note: you don't need to sort things to find a minimum. You can even keep track of your min and max as elements are added

Comment: I need to find the person that has the smallest name alphabetically, that being hagrid, since harry gets removed with the pop.

Comment: I understand that, but you don't need to sort anything to get that information

Comment: Well, do you at least have any idea why I get the error? And how I could get the information?

Comment: "must override or implement" message means you're not correctly defining all the methods from the interface. We don't know what methods are in the Queue interface you're implementing to answer that (please show your import statements)

Comment: I have now edited the post with all the other classes/interfaces

Comment: I have now seem to have fixed the error, but it still isn't giving me the correct output

Comment: As answered below, `public P min(Comparator<MedicalShifts> comp)` needs changed.  And you don't need your own Comparator interface (you're mixing Comparator and Comparable, which is probably part of the error)... Other than that, all the other methods seem fine

Comment: I am still not getting the desired output, my final line should be hagrid, but I am still getting ron

Comment: If I try using the method Arrays.sort(elements, comp), I get this error: The method sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (P[], Comparator<P>)If I try using the Arrays.sort(elements, comp) I get this error:

Comment: If you get the wrong output, and no error, then your code is actually compiling, so do **not** edit the method signatures, only the bodies

Comment: And yes, `Arrays.sort` takes a **Comparable** internal Java type, not your custom **Comparator** (which, like I said, you don't need unless it's required for your assignment)

Comment: I understand, but do you know how can I get the correct output? That being, sorting the array with the comparator. Because I actually need it for the assignment.

Comment: You already wrote a sorting algorithm inside the min function. Remove `Arrays.sort` from your code

Comment: That sorting algorithm is not working, even with the n variable declared since I didn't have it declared

Comment: You should be using `elements.length`, not `n`. You can lookup the algorithm for bubble sort in order to correct the problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question to focus on a single error. If you want to get the minimum value, you don't need to sort, only loop the array items once, and keep track of the smallest.

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed the generic and specific type. Your `min` should be generic on `P` (not specific on `MedicalShifts`). You wanted

```
@Override
public P min(Comparator<P> comp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
            if (comp.compare(elements[j], elements[j+1]) > 0) {
                P temp = elements[j];
                elements[j] = elements[j+1];
                elements[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return elements[0];
}
```

I don't know about sorting in a `min` function. Maybe

```
@Override
public P min(Comparator<P> comp) {
    P m = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (m == null || comp.compare(m, elements[i]) < 0) {
            m = elements[i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: I am now getting this error
Name clash: The method min(Comparator<P>) of type QueueImplement<P> has the same erasure as min(Comparator<MedicalShifts>) of type Queue<P> but does not override it

Comment: Which then says: The method min(Comparator<P>) of type QueueImplement<P> must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: By the way, `n` never seems to be defined anywhere

Comment: Yes, I seem to have removed the line when I tried fixing it

Answer (score 0):

Vos nos serás alumno mio no pibe? Ya te quiero ver en el oral :)))))

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.